# previous next with custom-post-type by order attribute

Tags: previous-post-link, menu-order

I have a custom-post-type called 'artists'. I list them by the order attribute (menu_order).

```
$args = array(
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'post_type'   => array('artists),
    'orderby'=> array('menu_order'=>'ASC' ),
);
$wp_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

When I use `the_post_navigation()` to get the previous and next links, it takes the date as the order instead of the `menu_order`. How can I get it to work right in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this function is better to use [get_adjacent_post](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_adjacent_post).

I have not tested it yet but it seems to more flexible than the_post_navigation() function.

FYI, the_post_navigation() uses this function internally to retrieve the next and previous posts.